# Test indirect method invocation using Mockito

Tags: java, mocking, testng, mockito

I have a method `a()` that, given the right circumstances should call another method `b()`. `b()` does not belong to a mocked object, but `a()` does.
I'm currently trying this:

`verify(mockedObject,times(1)).b();
notMocked.a();`

It seems that the invocation of `b()` is not captured by Mockito.

Thanks

Update: I came up with this hack to signal the method invocation, although I not happy at all with it.
`when(mocked.b()).thenThrow(new ItWasCalledException());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have done it in a different order.

`notMocked.a(); verify(mockedObject,times(1)).b();`

This works like a charm.